# Solution to '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've referenced other questions on this error but can't seem to find a solution for my case.

```
a = function(x)   
b = function(y)

if a == None:
   print("Invalid a")
if b == None
   print("Invalid b")
if a > b:
   print("Review")

Error: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I understand what the error means based on my research, but I'm not certain on how to fix it. Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: Try using `elif`.

Comment: Please make this a fully running example script. We don't know what `function1` and `function2` are. Is one of them returning `None`? How about just setting `a` and `b` for test? And didn't one of those `print` statements print something? Include that with your output. We should see the output of a script that we can run ourselves, plus the full traceback message.

Comment: *"I understand what the error means based on my research, but I'm not certain on how to fix it"* - so how can we help? You didn't state what you expect the code to do. How can we know what is the "fix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to an `if/else` statement, I'd suggest using a `try/except` block, which should be slightly more efficient if the `except` condition is generally not satsified.

Also, per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the comparison with None should be with `is` or `is not`, instead of `==` and `!=`.

```py
a = 21
b = None

try:
    if a > b:
        print("Review")

except TypeError:
    if a is None:
       print("Invalid a")
    elif b is None:
       print("Invalid b")
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: I was actually in the process of trying that, but just added in the 'elif'. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `elif`:

```
a = function(x)   
b = function(y)

if a == None:
   print("Invalid a")
elif b == None
   print("Invalid b")
elif a > b:
   print("Review")
```

Otherwise, there's still the possibility that `a` or `b` is `None` as all comparisons are independent of each other in your code.

Comment: should use `is` to check equality with None, not `==`